# How to extract a number of a txt and pass to an array

Tags: python

I have a .txt with 10 lines like this:

```
[-3 -4 -5 -6 -7], 0
```

I want to extract the number between [...] and pass them to an array of integers, i'm reading the .txt like this:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

I need to divide the part before the coma?
There is any function to do this?
What should i do?

Comment: You can read the file line-by-line into a variable, let's call it `line`, and then use the `split` function like so: `array_str, other_num = line.split(', ')`. You can then split the numbers on the left using `array_str[1:-1].split()` as split will operate on whitespace by default. The `[1:-1]` is to trim off the brackets. This gives you a list containing the numbers as strings.

Comment: I'm very sure i didn't ask anyone to do the code for me, but if there is a way to do and if there is some function to do it.

Comment: Even though you didn't _explicitly_ ask people to write the code for you, that's what you are actually asking with "What should I do?". Please read the links I shared, especially the one on [ask] a good question. Good questions include _your own attempts and research_ because at the end of the day, it's _your_ problem so you need to put in the effort to fix it.

Comment: Additionally, including what you already tried in your question lets the people answering see what didn't work, so that they don't need to spend time trying the same thing. Or, if there's a small mistake in your implementation they can point it out. This is summarized in the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) and in [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    arrays = []
    for line in contents.split('\n'):
        array_string = line.split(',')[0]
        array = [int(i) for i in array_string[1:-1].split()]
        arrays.append(array)
```

This will return, based on your example:

```
arrays

[[-3, -4, -5, -6, -7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that, but it's a bit meaty:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    new_list = [item.split(',')[0][1:-1].split() for item in f.readlines()]
    print(new_list)
```

my fault, hasn't seen that file will be provided like argument, then

```
#!/bin/python3

from sys import argv

with open(argv[1], 'r') as f:
    new_list = [item.split(',')[0][1:-1].split() for item in f.readlines()]
    print(new_list)
```

by the way, regex solution, also seems good:

```
with open(argv[1], 'r') as f:
    new_list = [re.findall('-?\d+', item.split(',')[0]) for item in f.readlines()]
    print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
test = "[-3 -4 -5 -6 -7], 0"

# split on the ','
test = test.split(",")
# remove the '[' and ']' and split on the whitespace
res = test[0].lstrip("[").rstrip("]").split(" ")
# add the standalone value to the the list?
res.append(test[1])
# cast values to int
res = [int(x) for x in res]

# print out the result
print(res)
```

result:

> [-3, -4, -5, -6, -7, 0]

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data to a list with a single line, as follows.

```
import sys

data = [ [ int(field) for field in row.split(sep=",")[0][1:-1].split() ] for row in open(sys.argv[1])]
```

You will get e.g.:

```
[[-3, -4, -5, -6, -7]]
```

The read mode is default for `open`, so you can omit it.
You go through the lines of the file.
For each row, you split the row by the "," separator.
The left part you can split simply to a list.
This list contains string fields which you can convert to int.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import sys
import re 

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    arrays = []
    for line in contents.split('\n'):
        string = line.split(',')[0]
        arrays.append(re.findall("[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?",string))
```